# Send email throught SMTP server postfix local to internet (gmail, oulook, yahoo)

Tags: linux, server

I have been trying to use my local SMTP server to send emails to internet domains (Gmail, Outlook, Yahoo)

I managed to send emails to the internet but using google smtp as smtp relay.

But what I want to accomplish is to send mails to the internet using my local server, without using smtp relay

Has anyone achieved something like this?
Or is it necessary to use an SMTP relay to send emails to external domains?
What configuration should I do in my local smtp recognize these domains?

My SMTP server is in Postfix on CentOS 6.8

Comment: Certainly you can use your own smtp server to send out emails. Question is why you failed to do so. We cannot tell you, without you posting much more precise details about your issues...

Comment: that is the purpose of having a smtp server. it can accept mails from your domain and send it to the destination. google,yahoo etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can but it is a lot of work, even considering you have the server ready. If you really want to be authentic and want to appear on inbox of the receiver instead of spam folder, you need to be consistent about reverse DNS, server IP, DKIM and so on. See google guidelines [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en).

Unless there is a good reason, I recommend you to continue using existing mail services to get rid of that maintenance cost.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your comments

I was able to solve my doubts, my problem was more about concepts of mail and dns, so I started to investigate and study very thoroughly to understand each concept about how communication is when sending an email.
I tell them what I did.
Troubleshooting, when I tried to send an email to an external domain in the / var / log / maillog file, I noticed that my mail server was not able to resolve, so I added the relay_domain field in the main.cf configuration file. Relay
Reading logs again I saw that my server was able to communicate with the internet smtp, but because I do not have a static public IP or logs in a master dns my submissions were bounced. But that was enough to understand that my settings were correct. In addition I started to study in depth about the types of records that are made in a DNS and the method of communication that they perform to solve external domains. (A, MX, PTR, CNAME, NS and SOA).

Very essential to understand the concepts and to do the troubleshooting with the maillogs. :)

Thanks for your comments! :)

Answer (score -1):

If you have Postfix you have the software already installed. Look at /etc/postfix/main.cf for settings. Postfix is very capable. Unless you are on a VM like Google or AWS where you may not have the ability to send even with Postfix. Then you can look at third party smtp gateways. Sendgrid and Mandrill/MailChimp handle this too.